# SQL: is it possible to return a table that only has one row per user when each user can have multiple conditions with corresponding diagnosis dates?

Tags: sql, sql-server, primary-key

I'm primarily a front-end developer, my experience with SQL and databases in general is very limited, so bear with me here.
So, here's my SQL query:

```
       Use UsersDB
       SELECT a.[UserID]
              ,a.[FirstName]
              ,a.[LastName]
              ,a.[DOB]
              ,b.[Allergy]
              ,b.[Severity]
              ,c.[ConditionName]
              ,c.[DiagnosisDate]
              ,d.[TestDate]
              ,e.[MedName]
              ,e.[StartDate]
              ,f.[VaccineName]
          FROM [UsersDB].[dbo].[vwUser] a
          INNER JOIN [dbo].[vwUserAllergy] b ON b.[UserID] = a.[UserID]
          INNER JOIN [dbo].[vwUserCondition] c on c.[UserID] = a.[UserID]
          INNER JOIN [dbo].[vwUserLabTest] d on d.[UserID] = a.[UserID]
          INNER JOIN [dbo].[vwUserMedication] e.[UserID] = e.[UserID]
          INNER JOIN [dbo].[vwUserVaccination] f on f.[UserID] = a.[UserID]
```

In this query, I'm joining multiple tables together on the UserID.

In my dashboard web application, I want to have a table of all users and I only want one row in that table per user. I'm using this query to generate the info to populate that table in my web application, but the problem I'm having is that this query returns multiple rows per user (because each user can have multiple conditions with respective dates, multiple medications with respective start dates, etc).

Is it possible to fix this?

Comment: The question is what data so you expect it to show, if a user has two allergies which do you expect to see? You'll either need to just show users in your main view and drill down to see the other data or you'll need to show the multiple rows and make it pretty with grouping in the UI.

Answer (score 0):

You can use cross apply with top 1 on this case.

You can add a ordering column on each apply, so that  you will have the latest or maybe the first record. It depends on your case.

```
    SELECT a.[UserID]
          ,a.[FirstName]
          ,a.[LastName]
          ,a.[DOB]
          ,b.[Allergy]
          ,b.[Severity]
          ,c.[ConditionName]
          ,c.[DiagnosisDate]
          ,d.[TestDate]
          ,e.[MedName]
          ,e.[StartDate]
          ,f.[VaccineName]
      FROM [UsersDB].[dbo].[vwUser] a
      CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 b1.[Allergy], b1.[Severity] FROM [dbo].[vwUserAllergy] b1 WHERE b1.[UserID] = a.[UserID]) b
      CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 c1.[ConditionName], c1.[DiagnosisDate] FROM [dbo].[vwUserCondition] c1 WHERE c1.[UserID] = a.[UserID]) c
      CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 d1.[TestDate] FROM [dbo].[vwUserLabTest] d1 WHERE d1.[UserID] = a.[UserID]) d
      CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 e1.[MedName], e1.[StartDate] FROM [dbo].[vwUserMedication] e1 WHERE e1.[UserID] = a.[UserID]) e
      CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 f1.[VaccineName] FROM [dbo].[vwUserVaccination] f1 WHERE f1.[UserID] = a.[UserID]) f
```

Comment: I tried to execute that query in SSMS, but it's giving me back incorrect syntax errors

Comment: The error I get is  "the multi-part identifier "d1.UserID" could not be bound" and that a number of the columns are invalid

Comment: My bad, the last cross apply screwed up. i have corrected it now.

Comment: Please try now, the last query was screwed up i forgot to change the condition and the selected column. try now

Comment: It says that MedName and StartDate are invalid column names

Comment: Awesome, it works now. So, this is just listing the first allergy, condition, etc for each user right? I wanted to see if there was a way to list all the conditions and allergies for each user in the same row...I wonder if that's even possible

Comment: yes, but it will repeat your previous issue which is repeating rows. you need to create a separate query for it. from there when you iterate for each record and call that procedure.

Comment: The question is not clear. Tell @AliciaGuerra that via a comment on the question (& downvote & close vote when you have rep), please don't guess at an answer.